# map choose `std::greater` or `std::less` at runtime

Tags: c++

This line:

```
std::map<long int, long int, std::greater<long int>> current_book;
```

I would like to replace it by the logical equivalent of:

```
int Side = ...
if (Side == 1){
    std::map<long int, long int, std::greater<long int>> current_book;
} else {
    std::map<long int, long int, std::less<long int>> current_book;
}
```

Comment: Can you solve it by just choosing one ordering, and then using the appropriate iterators, `begin`/`end` in one case, and `rbegin`/`rend` in the other?

Comment: btw your example has a serious flaw. The maps are local to the if-blocks and they are of different types, so you also cannot pull the declaration of `current_book` out of the if. Fortunately the answer solves that problem :)

Comment: Could `Side` be a template argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `std::function` for that:

```
using mymap = std::map<long,long,std::function<bool(long,long)>>;
auto m = Side ? mymap( std::less<long>() ) : mymap( std::greater<long>() );
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/hlgUtZ)

Comment: A neat solution, but a custom functor will probably have less overhead.

Comment: Difficult to chose among all these good answers. I went for the less verbose code;)

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement a custom comparator class, something along the lines of:

```
class map_comparator {

   bool less_than;

public:

   map_comparator(bool less_than) : less_than{less_than} {}

   bool operator()(long a, long b) const
   {
       if (less_than)
             return a < b;
       return a > b;
   }
};
```

And then use it to construct your map, using the constructor that takes an instance of the comparator class as a parameter, and then pass in the appropriately constructed comparator class instance:

```
std::map<long int, long int, map_comparator>
     current_book{ map_comparator{ Side != 1}};
```

Comment: Why not a lambda?

Comment: You can still pass `less_than` as a captured variable by value and have exactly the same effect. What you wrote up there is basically how lambdas unfold by the compiler. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Difficult to chose among all these good answers. I went for the less verbose code;)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist how would you declare the type of the map then?

Comment: @Quimby You just put `decltype` that lambda as the third template parameter.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist lambda expressions cannot be `decltype`d that's the problem.

Comment: @Quimby [There's always a way](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97c303897f3561f).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Well, then its a function, not a lambda and you have to have a variable in order to declare a type. In that case you could leave in `auto lambda=...;` and  declare map as `map<...,decltype(lambda)> m{lambda};` Declaring the map as member variable might be problematic. But sure, it works and so its a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a straight function pointer. This approach won't suffer from overhead of `if (less_than)` branching on each comparison or from overhead of `std::function`:

```
#include <map>

using t_Key = long int;
using t_Value = long int;
using t_Comparator = bool ( * )(t_Key const left, t_Key const right);
using t_Map = ::std::map<t_Key, t_Value, t_Comparator>;

bool Is_Less(t_Key const left, t_Key const right)
{
    return left < right;
}

bool Is_Greater(t_Key const left, t_Key const right)
{
    return left > right;
}

int main()
{
    int Side{};
    t_Map current_book{(Side == 1) ? &Is_Less : &Is_Greater};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Difficult to chose among all these good answers. I went for the less verbose code;)

Comment: For flexibility reuse less than operator for the type even in `bool Is_Greater(t_Key const left, t_Key const right)
{
    return right < left;
}` in case `t_Key` becomes something more complex in the future.

Comment: Do we need those ampersands?

Comment: @PaulSanders Not really, for some reason C++ allows implicit taking of function address.